# Grep --only-match without new line

Tags: grep

I want to use `grep` command to extract some strings from my data file.

data file format

```
a=1,b=2,c=3,
a=4,b=5,c=6,
```

I want the out format

```
a=1,c=3,
a=4,c=6,
```

I tried the below command

```
grep -Po 'a=.*?,|c=.*?,' data
```

But the output format is incorrect. Please teach me how to do it.

Comment: I suggest to use `cut` or `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: awk -F"," '{ print $1","$3"," }'

Answer (score 0):

One possibility with `sed` would be as follows.

```
sed -n 's/\(a=.\?,\)\(.*\)\(c=.\?\)/\1\3/p' data
```

A more generic regex would be as follows.

```
sed -n 's/\([a-zA-Z]=.\?,\)\([a-zA-Z]=.\?,\)\([a-zA-Z]=.\?,\)/\1\3/p' input
```

Comment: or `sed 's/,[^,]\+//' file`